# Expected token-error when inserting a variable into a string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

```
var value = liste[eigenschaft];
document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML = value;
var data = '{"products":[{"ingramPartNumber":"7U0169"}, {"ingramPartNumber":"6XH440"}]}';
```

I made a successful request for an API from one of our online-distributors.
In the var data (as shown above) I can list the name/value-pairs (e.g.: `ingramPartNumber` and the actual `partNumber`) and I get back the corresponding data.

However, we want to make the call a bit more dynamic. We implemented a search and we want to have the value of the search (in the example above the var value) as an actual value in var data.

However, if I substitute the product-number with the variable (as shown below), it throws an error (expected token identifier) .. What am I missing?

```
var value = liste[eigenschaft];
document.getElementById("demo6").innerHTML = value;
var data = '{"products":[{"ingramPartNumber":"7U0169"}, {"ingramPartNumber":"'value'"}]}';
```

Comment: You need to either use string interpolation or string concatenation via `+`.

Comment: Learn about [string concatenation in JS](https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/fundamentals/string-concat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing this

```
   var data = '{"products":[{"ingramPartNumber":"7U0169"}, {"ingramPartNumber":"'value'"}]}';
```

Where you should be using interpolation or concatenation

```
   var data = '{"products":[{"ingramPartNumber":"7U0169"}, {"ingramPartNumber":' + value + '}]}';
```

Comment: This does neither interpolation nor concatenation.